# How to hide a table in hbase?

Tags: hbase

I looked up Hbase definitive guide, but to no avail. Couldnt find any substantial. My table needs to be hidden for security reasons. Does hbase allow such a provision?

Comment: can you elaborate your use case a bit more?

Comment: i have a table which i store configuration details. I dont want to expose the table to the enduser. is there any way to hide the table?